# nuget: "The replacement token 'id' has no value"

Tags: nuget

Executing

```
nuget.exe pack ..\.nuget\nuget.exe pack ..\pathToProject\myproject.nuspec -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Configuration=Release
```

I get the error

```
The replacement token 'id' has no value.
```

The nuspec looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>$id$</id>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <title>$id$</title>
        <authors>$author$</authors>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>$description$</description>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

When using token replacement, make sure your are trying to nuget pack the **csproj** file, not the **nuspec** file

```
nuget pack myproject.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Configuration=Release
```

The nuspec is picked up automatically when given the same name as the csproj file.

Comment: You forgot the dash in front of the IncludeReferencedProjects parameter.  Should be:

nuget.exe pack ..\.nuget\nuget.exe pack ..\pathToProject\myproject.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Configuration=Release

Comment: I think it's pretty stupid when you use pack my.csproj it doesn't respect your nuspec file, and when you use pack my.nuspec it doesn't respect tokens. it boggles my mind how this gets created.

Comment: When packing csproj, it picks up the nuspec of the same name. Seems reasonable to me? The error when packing nuspec with variables could be more intuitive though

Comment: The best part is that neither will detect dependencies. Most of the "Automatic" stuff doesn't actually work at all.