# TFS 2015 Build Task - NuGet Packager

Tags: c#, tfsbuild, nuget-package, tfs-2015

I am currently setting up a build definition to package a NuGet. Here is my current build task. It is executed after the solution successfully builds.

[image]

I am using a nuspec file to decide what information the package will display. My nuspec file contains references to the information (i.e. pulled from the assemblyinfo.cs file).

[image]

Running the build definition I receive the following error.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Are the replacement tokens not supported within TFS 2015 under the Package NuGet task?

Comment: Could you pack with nuspec file successfully in local with nuget command directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The packager does not replace tokens in the .nuspec file (except the
>   `<version/>` element). You must supply values for elements such as
>   `<id/>` and `<description/>`. The most common way to do this is to
>   **hardcode** the values in the `.nuspec` file.
>
> Source Link: [**Pack NuGet packages**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget#pack-nuget-packages)

When using **token replacement**, make sure your are trying to nuget pack the **csproj** file, not the **nuspec** file

```
nuget pack myproject.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects -Prop Configuration=Release
```

The nuspec is picked up automatically when given the same name as the csproj file.

Please refer this similar question: [nuget: "The replacement token 'id' has no value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580558/nuget-the-replacement-token-id-has-no-value)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's disappointing that the packager cannot replace the tokens from a build. I have no issue on my local machine replacing the tokens through the nuspec.

Comment: @Brian  Sorry for the inconvenience.  As a workaround, you need either hardcode the values or use `.csproj`  file to pack,

Comment: Are there any plans to add this functionality to the build task? Thanks again for the info Patrick.

Comment: @Brian  So far no word that they can, still not available in the latest version TFS2017 update. You could add a [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services) and any update will let you know asap.